# cannot send object over MSMQ inside WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq

I've got some legacy code which sends objects over an MSMQ messagequeue. It worked fine but now the code is moved to a WCF service. Now suddenly limits are reached and the queue.Send line throws the exception:

> "Insufficient resources to perform operation".

I'm not using netMsmqBinding, just sending it through MessageQueue objects so I dont know how to increase the quotum of the objects size.

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queueName);

using (MessageQueueTransaction tx = queue.Transactional ? new MessageQueueTransaction() : null)
{
    if (queue.Transactional)
    {
      tx.Begin();
    }

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.Body = delivery;
    msg.Label = delivery.GetType().Name + " " + delivery.DeliveryId;
    msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Delivery) });
    msg.Recoverable = true;
    queue.Send(msg, tx);
}
```

After implementing IErrorhandler on the service for logging exceptions I see this right before the resources:

> 12/10/2015 7:54:06 AM Uncaught exception of type
>   System.TimeoutException was thrown. Message: 'The operation did not
>   complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:09.9970000. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.'

I've put all the timeouts (open/close/receive/send) on the client and service to 45 minutes and still this error of 10 seconds timeout comes. Strange.

What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like your MSMQ storage has hit the ~2 gig limit. Do you have any queues that are holding a lot of messages? As a note, MSMQ is not meant for long term storage. It is a queue, and should never hold on to queued items. When a message is added, it should be picked up by another process almost immediately.

Comment: @Servé Laurijssen  What binding are you using ?If NetTcpBinding you can   // QUOTAS
            binding.MaxConnections = 200;
            binding.ListenBacklog = 800;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue; 
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;             binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 128;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;

Comment: @Serve` Laurijseen - sorry my bad - upon re-reading your post - I Gargled and came to a link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx
And https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899613

Comment: How big are the objects? MSMQ messages are max 4MB.

Comment: Are you using netMsmqBinding on the service side?

Comment: Wait, I just read your question. So you are trying to send a message as a result of someone calling the WCF service?

Comment: Where is invocation of Commit method on transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem, it was my own fault.
I had removed [XmlIgnore] attribute from the two biggest members of Delivery. And since Delivery was serialized with XmlMessageFormatter for message queueing the object was simply too big for the queue.

Sorry to bother you....

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is that you are reaching the storage/memory limit of MSMQ (~2GB) due to 1 or more reasons.

1. Messages are accumulating in one of your queues and are not being processed and removed. (Most likely)
2. Journaling is turned on.
3. Deadletter queues are filling up.

You can quickly check the queue sizes by checking the properties of the folder: `%windir%\system32\msmq\storage`.

Comment: The 2GB limit was in Windows 2000! That limitation disappeared in Windows XP and above.

Comment: The question does not specify what server version is being used. I just know what I have run into in the past.